# Trying to supply PGPASS to Docker Image

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

New to Docker here. I'm trying to create a basic Dockerfile where I run a python script that runs some queries in postgres through psycopg2. I currently have a pgpass file setup in my environment variables so that I can run these tools without supplying a password in the code. I'm trying to replicate this in Docker. I have windows on my local.

```
FROM datascienceschool/rpython as base
RUN mkdir /test
WORKDIR /test
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY main_airflow.py /test
RUN cp C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf /test
ENV PGPASSFILE="test/pgpass.conf"
ENV PGUSER="user"
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/test/main_airflow.py"]
```

This is what I've tried in my Dockerfile. I've tried to copy over my pgpassfile and set it as my environment variable. Apologies if I have a forward/backslashes wrong, or syntax. I'm very new to Docker, Linux, etc.

Any help or alternatives would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to pass your secrets into the container at runtime than it is to include the secret in the image at build-time. This means that the `Dockerfile` doesn't need to know anything about this value.

For example

```sh
$ export PGPASSWORD=<postgres password literal> 
$ docker run -e PGPASSWORD <image ref>
```

Now in that example, I've used `PGPASSWORD`, which is [an alternative to PGPASSFILE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-envars.html). It's a little more complicated to do this same if you're using a file, but that would be something like this:

The plan will be to mount the credentials as a volume at runtime.

```
FROM datascienceschool/rpython as base
RUN mkdir /test
WORKDIR /test
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY main_airflow.py /test
ENV PGPASSFILE="/credentials/pgpass.conf"
ENV PGUSER="user"
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/test/main_airflow.py"]
```

As I said above, we don't want to include the secrets in the image. We are going to indicate where the file *will be* in the image, but we don't actually include it yet.

Now, when we start the image, we'll mount a volume containing the file at the location specified in the image, `/credentials`

```sh
$ docker run --mount src="<host path to directory>",target="/credentials",type=bind <image ref>
```

I haven't tested this so you may need to adjust the exact paths and such, but this is the idea of how to set sensitive values in a docker container

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the explanation, this is very useful. I tried passing my PGPASSWORD and PGUSER during runtime, and I'm still getting a "No password supplied" error. I needed to change up the syntax from "export" to "$Env:" because I'm just running it in Windows powershell. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and have been trying to find a solution lol. Either way, thank you for explaining that it's better to pass secrets during runtime, than build time.

Comment: now would be a good time to run the container interactively
`$ docker run -it <image ref> bash` and see if your environment variable is set as you want within the container. I'm afraid I can't help much with the windows variations, though

Comment: Oh nevermind, it worked! I just needed to put the image name after -e PGPASSWORD. Thank you!